# How to set Google Voice to show my GV number for incoming calls?

Tags: google-voice

I have a Google Voice number linked to my cell phone.  When someone calls my GV number, the caller ID shows as that person's number. I would like to know that the call is coming from Google Voice, and I thought that I could set it so that GV calls show my GV number in the caller ID.

I followed the instructions [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/voice/Ydbw3lm0mUs), but I wasn't able to find the **Caller ID (Incoming)** option in either current Call tab or the legacy Phone tab.  Has this option been removed entirely from both the current version and the legacy version?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

1. From the "new" Google Voice interface at https://voice.google.com/, open the Settings hamburger menu in the upper left, then choose "Legacy Google Voice" in the sidebar.
2. In the legacy interface, choose the settings gear near the upper right, then click Settings.
3. Navigate to the Calls tab.
4. In the second item down, called "Caller ID (incoming)," change the option to "Display my Google Voice number."

I also couldn't find this setting in the new interface, so I hope they are not removing this toggle!

Comment: Sept 2019. I can't find in the newest UI.